# Webclient slow on the first request

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm creating an app that gets info from a website, this website returns a single line of text with the data. 
To get this I'm just using `WebClient.DownloadString()`. This is the code:

```
    {
        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        Client.Proxy = null;
        return Client.DownloadString(url);
    }
```

The problem is that on the first request this process always takes  `~21.000ms`, the next ones take normal amounts of time. There are similar questions, and pepole seem to solve this probelm adding the line `Client.Proxy = null;`, but it dones't fix my problem. My proxy internet settings are disabled, and the firewall isn't blocking anything (tried disabling it).

I also tested using diferent websites such as google (to test it's not a server problem), but the results are the same. I also tried using a `WebBrowser` control and `HttpWebRequest`, but the results are also the same.

On regular browsers(tested edge, firefox and chrome) loading the same page takes about `200ms` with cache cleared.

Using wireshark I got this, but I don't know how to interpret it:

With firefox:

```
TCP:
1. SYN (client-server)
2. SYN (client-server)
3. SYN ACK (server-client)
4. ACK (client-server)
5. SYN ACK (server-client)    
6. ACK (client-server)       
HTTP:
5. GET (client-server)   
TCP:
7. ACK (server-client)   
HTTP:
5. RESPONSE 200 OK (server-client) (The correct response is received)
TCP:
7. ACK (client server)
```

Then with my program:

I get the exact same procedure, but the first sent packet over TCP uses Ipv6 adresses instead of Ipv4, then it waits 21s and then the rest of the packets, the actual HTTP GET-RESPONSE time is short as it should be.

Comment: When a connection is made to a http server there is a negotiation that occurs between client and server using the http headers to get a common mode of communications.  For example the server made default to French and the client may want English.  The server then will forward the URL to another webpage which may take time.  Also a cookie may be established on first connection and then subsequent connections will use cookie so the response using the cookie will be quicker than initial connection without cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved it was Ipv6 all along. Instead of doing the request to `http://www.hostame.domian/file` I'm now doing `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/file`, so it directly goes to a Ipv4 adress.

Kind of a short living question , but I hope it helps if someone has the same problem.